# Which functionality of Android should I use to show a long list in android in multiple pages?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a very large list of items(N) from a sqlite database.At a time I want to show only that number of items that can fit in the screen of my mobile.Let's say it comes out as 'x'.Then I want the swipe functionalty such that user swipes the screen and a new page comes on the screen with next 'x' items in a ListView with total number of N/x pages.
In short I want the ViewPager type functionalty.But I cannot figure out which android classes  to use.

Comment: The basic way i can think of now, firstly i'll try to design a function of screen height that will tell me how many item can i fit in that screen(X). Next i'll use two fragments and populate those alternately with data after every X length then use gesture and animation to get swipe function

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be a ListView with a load more or auto load more type functionality. When the user scrolls down far enough it will either have a load more button as a ListView footer or you can auto detect it and load more for them and potentially display a progress bar as a footer.

Swiping side to side is usually for related content not more of the current content.